# What is the difference between Private properties with set/get and private properties without set get in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. We declare Private member variable in a class to make them inaccessible from outside the class in which they are declared, but we can do this simply declaring them 'private' so what's the need of using set and get with them? for e.g i have a class customer

```
class Customer 
    {
        private double TotalPurchases; // { get; set; }
        private string Name; // { get; set; }
        private int CustomerID; // { get; set; }
        public Customer(double tp, string nam, int id) 
        {
            TotalPurchases = tp;
            Name = nam;
            CustomerID = id;
        }

        public void value() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total purchases so far " + TotalPurchases + " " + Name + " " + CustomerID);
        }
    }

    class Program 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            // Intialize a new object.
            Customer cust1 = new Customer(20.0, "C#", 10);
            cust1.value();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

when i remove comment in customer class and allow properties to use set and get, it makes no difference at all!!!

Comment: without get set is field not property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `get; set;` it behaves as `Field` and with `Field` there is no control over when and how the `Field` is assigned or retrieved.

If `get set` is present, you can control what value remains in Property based on some logic.

```
private string _foo;
public string Foo
{
    get
    {
        if (_foo == null) return string.Empty;
        return _foo;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        _foo = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That being said, they are also formally different in the sense that reflection permits to access them seperately.

Comment: @Codor: Yes, exactly and that is how it should behave. Reflection or no reflection.